# netbeans amazon elastic bean connection

Tags: netbeans, amazon-ec2, region, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I tried to connect my Netbeans with Amazon I run int a problem, for some reason it could find my environment setup, and they I figured out what was the problem. I have an environment in the non default region (namely mine is in the EU and not the USA-Verginia))

Is there an ability to switch this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue has been fixed:
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=219665

Update your Netbeans version to 7.3 to see the new version of the Beanstalk plugin.